# Is it possible to show in the project view of Netbeans whether a class is public or package-private?

Tags: java, netbeans, dependency-management, netbeans-plugins, class-visibility

My team would like to be able to clearly see which classes in a package are public. Unfortunately there seems to be no visual indication of this in the Netbeans project view. Is there any way of adding the behaviour we want? If not, will the plugin API allow me to write a plugin which adds this behaviour myself?

Alternatively, what other solutions are there to get a basic high-level look at the visibility and dependants of classes in a package? Going in to each class, checking its visibility, and doing a 'Find Usages' is not convenient.

Comment: Which version of NetBeans are you using? The latest 7.3?

Comment: 7.2.1, but could update.

Comment: Well in that case you might want to try updating to see whether that includes what you're looking for. You never know.

Comment: It's not possible in 7.3 either.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you want to check your class definitions, public or private. 
You can use Find window, search "public class", "private class" keyword, match case, whole word, and use file pattern "*.java". Maybe you want to use UML diagrams, there is a plugin for that.

Comment: Searching doesn't really help me. I thought of UML diagrams yesterday, and found out that the official UML plugin hasn't worked for about 5 versions!

Comment: yes, you are right, i'm also waiting for new version support. Install netbeans 6, clone your project files, open your clone project in netbeans 6. And use UML plugin. I know this is very annoying...